# DependencyProperty.UnsetValue using template and MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

Anyone knows why I receive the error: "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue" when I call my Command through the **Template**
This is my template:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuComboBoxItemTemplate" DataType="ComboBox">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Text.Display}" />
        <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" 
                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                ToolTip="Delete"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Padding="2"
                Margin="3,0,0,0"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.RemoveMenuItemCommand}">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Name" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type menus:MenuComboBox}}" />
                    <Binding />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
            <Image Source="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=Delete_16x16.png}" />
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My combobox:

```
<menus:MenuComboBox 
        x:Name="MyItems" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Padding="6,3,5,3" 
        BorderThickness="1"
        Text="{Binding MyItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuComboBoxItemTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Menus[MyItems].Items}" 
        NewMenuItemCommand="{Binding AddMenuItemCommand}"
        GotFocusCommand="{Binding GotFocusCommand}" />
```

I am stuck on it :(

Comment: As a note, `DataType="ComboBox"` doesn't make sense. You should remove it.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in your converter to check which of the Bindings produces UnsetValue?

Comment: Hi Clemens, yes I set a breakpoint on my converter and it is UnsetValue.

Comment: So which of the two values is it?

Comment: The **Name** is UnsetValue. The second one is the option(text) and it is working this one.

Comment: Are you sure the Name property of the MenuComboBox is actually set? You may perhaps simply omit `Path="Name" in the Binding and directly access the MenuComboBox in your converter.

Comment: The Name is set for sure. But this is happen probably because I am using a style.xaml from another project which is in the same solution. But funnily the command `RemoveMenuItemCommand` is triggering so I am missing something about `RelativeSource` I guess so

Comment: You should perhaps also show how you are using the DataTemplate.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to format on comment but the format does not apply in comment

Comment: Ok, I edit the question.